# Error using 'Clip raster by mask' in QGIS v3.8.2

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

I am attempting to clip a raster to a shapefile boundary (country boundary, 1 polygon) using the 'clip raster by mask' tool in QGIS v3.8.2. 
Both layers are in WGS84, so projection mismatch shouldn't be the issue.

I'm getting the following error message that I haven't been able to sort out:

> 2019-09-09T16:23:13 INFO GDAL execution console output
>   Creating output file that is 435P x 193L.
>   Processing R:\exampledata\wc20_25m_tmin_01.tif [1/1] : 0ERROR 1: IllegalArgumentException: point array must contain 0 or >1 elements
>
> ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.
>
> Using internal nodata values (e.g. -3.4e+38) for image R:\exampledata\wc20_25m_tmin_01.tif.
>
> Copying nodata values from source R:\exampledata\wc20_25m_tmin_01.tif to destination 
>   C:/Temp/processing_7b281fab84954f6ca3dd66d12d696f5c/0b2ef639021f42f0b744260b98b85235/OUTPUT.tif.

To correct this I've tried:

1) checking the geometry of the polygon file, no errors were found. Geometry is valid

2) correcting the geometry anyway. No change.

3) creating a zero distance buffer, didn't fix it.

4) tried a different vector shapefile, same issue.

5) tried a different raster with both shapefiles, same issue.

6) tried simplifying the geometry, no change to the issue.

7) discovered the single feature is in fact a 'multi polygon'. tried deleteing all the small features and saving the main area as a single polygon. This did not correct the issue.

8) Using the SAGA 'clip raster with polygon' tool. This produces a usable output with a warning:

> Loading resulting layers
>   The following layers were not correctly generated.
>
> - C:/Users/wkessler/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_1b387f0cf3564641840068eedfe5ec05/cf6aaedbd8e44f09b1eeb194d5d23a36/OUTPUT.sdat
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Now, I have tried the same operation in both QGIS 2.18 (Clipper tool) and ArcGIS 10.6 (Clip) and have no issues. I have also managed to get the SAGA 'clip raster with polygon' function to work on this data in QGIS 3.8.2, although it does give a warning that the result was generated incorrectly. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

EDIT: Since posting this question I have also sent the data to a friend who tried the operations using QGIS 3.8.2, 3.4, and 2.18. They found the same thing; that it works in 2.18 but not in 3.4 or 3.8.2.

EDIT 2: tried additional solutions suggested by comments. None have solved the issue.

Comment: Have you checked if both shapefile and raster file have the same projection?

Comment: @ahmadhanb , yes, both files have the same projection.

Comment: I've been fighting the same problem with a fairly complex shoreline of Alaska. I also found a similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333194/cant-cut-raster-with-a-polygon-shapefile/334059#334059. I did not try the simplification @d_araujo used, but I did delete all islands and was able to clip to the single mainland polygon. Perhaps a simplification process would help solve your error since you already have a single polygon?

Comment: @snow-raven Thanks for the suggestion. I realized that while my shapefile only contains one feature, it is in fact a 'multipolygon' i.e. there are many small islands. I tried converting the shapefile to single parts and save off the mainland area, effectively removing all the small islands. This did not fix the issue either.

Comment: @snow-raven I also tried the simplification suggested in the question you linked to. That did not correct the issue.